# Alert Message doesn't seem to be readable or displayed on discord

Tags: json, discord, alert

I have several messages setup to post to discord, the alert message displayed seems to be the correct format

Each message is set to variable: mesg

The alert is set to `alert(mesg, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)`

```
'{ "content" : " '+syminfo.ticker+', /n BEARISH MSB at '+ str.tostring(bemsb_price) +',  /n New Bearish OB Zone : '+ str.tostring(p_top) + ', - ' + str.tostring(p_bottom) +', \n Current Price: '+str.tostring(close)+'," }'
```

All the alerts work, and seem to display it in the correct format, however, nothing is displayed in discord, and yes, i have setup the webhook 100% correctly